# Отправка сообщений pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Пробую отправлять пользователям сообщения таким образом:

```
await app.send_message(userid, 'test_spam_mail')
```

На что получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it
```

У меня уже есть чаты с этими пользователями и pyrogram просит вместо userid chat_id.
Как получить этот чат ид, имея только userid, get_users и get_chat тоже почему то не работают

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке Pyrogram для получения chat_id по user_id нужно использовать метод get_chat и атрибут id.

```
from pyrogram import Client

# Создаем экземпляр клиента
app = Client("my_account")

# Получаем chat_id по user_id
def get_chat_id(user_id):
    chat = app.get_chat(user_id)
    return chat.id

user_id = 123456789
chat_id = get_chat_id(user_id)
print(chat_id)

# Останавливаем клиент
app.stop()
```

Если у вас по какой-то причине не работает `get_chat`, то отредактируйте ваш вопрос и прикрепите ошибку.